# Как сработал этот 301 редирект?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Сначала я написал правило для переписывания URL.

```
RewriteRule ^new$ new.php
```

Далее, чтобы избавиться от дублирования путей к файлам, сделал редирект от старого URL в новому, и разместил его до уже написанного правила.

```
RewriteRule ^new.php$ /new [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^new$ new.php
```

Первая запись должна подставлять новый адрес, вместо старого, а вторая - давать доступ к реальному файлу по новому имени. Но такая запись выдаёт ошибки переадресации. Но если закомментировать первую запись, запись начинает работать как предполагалось, но ровно да тех пор, пока не очистить кэш. Почему так происходит, и как зафиксировать необходимый результат без комментирования?

Comment: Потому что, очевидно, new.php редиректит на new, а new редиректит на new.php. Правда, как исправить, фиг знает (лично я вообще не делал бы ничего подобного)

Comment: Ваши правила обрабатываются так - клиент пришел на new.php редиректим его на /new, затем он пришел на /new редиректим его на new.php, так он пришел на new.php редиретким его на /new и так пока не сработает To many redirect. Поясните зачем вам с new.php по факту переходить на new.php ?

Comment: Нужно чтобы при вводе new.php и new, в строке было new, и открывался реальный фал new.php. Первый запрос переписывает строку, второй по этой строке выдаёт файл. Само по себе первое правило редиректит на new, но сервер выдаёт ошибку, что такой страницы нет, её и на самом деле нет. То, что там цикл, очевидно, но он как-то работает.